# Row by Row processing in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, recursive-query

I am using Hive SQL server. In my database, I am trying to remove records which have less than 7 days of the gap with the previous record but when removing the record I want to check the gap with a "previous retained record", not with any previous record.

[image: Snapshot of the database:]

I want to retain all the record marked as 1 specifically Rec # 7 Although the gap of 7th record is <7, since the previous record is being removed the gap of 7th with 5th becomes 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative max:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when retained = 1 then intdate end) over (order by intdate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_intdate
      from t
     ) t
where prev_intdate is null or
      prev_intdate > dateadd(intdate, 7);
```